# PowerShell cmdlets to get Microsoft Teams usage report are not working, why?

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get Microsoft Teams usage report using PowerShell. To do so, initially I am connecting to Teams with "Connect-MicrosoftTeams", then to see the cmdlets i executed the command "Get-Command -Module MicrosoftTeams". Both cmdlets are working fine.
But after this I am not able to proceed further, when I am trying to get GroupId using "Get-Team" , i am getting nothing. When I executed the Get-Team command it took 3 minutes 8 Second & 386 milliseconds and then the cursor got return without any output nor any error message(please see the screenshot [image: PowerShell cmdlets output]).
None of the cmdlets with "Get-* " is working.for example: get-Team -displayName, Get-Team -user none is working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting with an admin account that has access to read from the administrative information of Microsoft Teams?

Additionally, make sure to install the module with the flag `-AllowClobber` if you haven't, it caused me some issues initially.

Personally I was able to pull the teams on our infrastructure that I had access to manage:
[image: Teams Count Console]

[image: Amount of Teams O365]

Comment: Thanks for your response. with this count I got zero(o). What does it mean then?I do have role "Reports Reader"only in Microsoft 365 Admin center. Do I need others role to execute this cmdlets?If so, which role should I be on?

Comment: I got Teams Service Admin, but based on your specific organization (if you can't have admin creds) it may be wise to reach out to Microsoft's support to see what roles you will need in order to access that module. I looked through the roles however and couldn't see anything obvious regarding it, so the admin access may be a requirement.

Comment: You need to be a Teams Service administrator in order to manage the teams in the organization and their associated settings, including membership.

Comment: @Riley Carney Thanks a lot. One last question: Will "Global Reader " role work in Teams Administrator Service in this aspect??

Comment: Global Reader looks like it should work, however I'm not positive without testing :)

Comment: oof, definitely need teams service admin then.